# Using PHP $_SESSION

Tags: php, session

I am setting `$_SESSION` values via a form:

```
<?php if(!empty($_POST)){ 

  session_start();    
  foreach ($_POST AS $key => $value) {
   $_SESSION['$key'] = $value;
  }

?>
```

Subsequent pages on the website can access the data:

Putting `var_dump($_SESSION);` on another page shows:

```
array(2) { ["post"]=> array(5) { ["nickname"]=> string(6) "Andrew" ["gender"]=> string(4) "Male" ["button"]=> string(0) "" ["age"]=> string(7) "Unknown" ["location"]=> string(7) "Unknown" } ["$key"]=> string(7) "Unknown" }
```

I am trying to get a value using:

```
params.nick      = "<?php session_start(); echo $_SESSION['nickname']; ?>";
```

but it doesn't show Andrew.

Am I using this wrong?

Comment: tell him what was erong and help him instead downvoting

Comment: You need to explain the `params.nick      = "<?php session_start(); echo $_SESSION['nickname']; ?>";`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have multiple issues:

Having `$key` inside of single quotes causes the variables not to be interpolated. Just put the `$key` without any quotes are none are needed.

```
<?php 
session_start(); 
if(!empty($_POST)){ 
  foreach ($_POST AS $key => $value) {
    $_SESSION[$key] = $value;
  }
}
?>
```

You only need to put `session_start()` at the top of the page *once* and then you can access session variables normally on the rest of the page.

```
params.nick = "<?php echo $_SESSION['nickname']; ?>";
```

Answer (score 0):

Just use:

```
session_start();
$_SESSION = array_merge($_SESSION, $_POST);
```